# Mongoose : How to find documents in which fields match an ObjectId or a string?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is mongoose DataModel in NodeJs

`product: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'products', required: true}`

But in DB, this field is having multiple type of values in documents, have `String` and `ObjectId`

I'm querying this in mongoose

```
{
    $or: [
        {
            "product": "55c21eced3f8bf3f54a760cf" 
        }
        ,
        {
            "product": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("55c21eced3f8bf3f54a760cf") 
        }
    ]
}
```

But this is only fetching the documents which have that field stored as ObjectId.

Is there any way that it can fetch all the documents having both type of values either `String` OR `ObjectId`?

Help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Mongoose can only work with fields of a single type. If you want to use Mongoose, you'll need to clean up your docs so that `product` is always one type.

Comment: thanks @JohnnyHK I'll have to update the documents to Same type first. Got it.

Comment: `Mixed` data type is also an solution! @JohnnyHK. `mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed`

Comment: Good point, but that's basically like no type at all, so use with caution as you won't get any type casting or change detection. It's still best to clean up your docs to be consistent.

Answer (score 3):

There is a schema in Mongoose, so when you query a document, it will search it by this schema type. If you change the model's product type to "string", it will fetch only documents with string IDs.

Even if there is a way to fetch either a `string` OR `ObjectId`, it's smelly to me to have such inconsistency.

I've encountered the same problem, so the solution was to standardize all documents by running a script to update them.

```
db.products.find().forEach(function(product) {
  db.products.update({ type: product.type},{
      $set:{ type: ObjectId(data.type)}
  });
});
```

The only problem I see there is if this `type` field is actually an `_id` field. _id fields in MongoDB are immutable and they can't be updated. If that is your case, you can simply create a new document with the same (but parsed) id and remove the old one.

This is what I did: <sub>(in Robomongo)</sub>

```
db.getCollection('products').find().forEach(
    function(doc){
        var newDoc = doc;
        newDoc._id = ObjectId(doc._id);

        db.getCollection('products').insert(newDoc);
    }
)
```

Then delete all documents, which id is a string:

```
db.getCollection('products').find().forEach(
    function(doc){
        db.getCollection('products').remove({_id: {$regex: ""}})
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ylin, I need to update that field's type to one in all the documents.

Comment: `Mixed` data type is also an solution, like `mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed`

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to do this. If we Update the `type` to `Mixed` then it will fetch all the documents with each type, either `String` or `ObjectId`

Define this in your Schema

`mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed`

Like

`product: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true}`